# Making bean definitions in Groovy Bean Definition DSL order-independent

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-groovy-config

The only downside I currently see in the new [Groovy Bean Definition DSL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_groovy_bean_definition_dsl) is that the beans in the closure must be declared in the dependency order. For example, while this works:

```
beans {
    repository(RepositoryImpl)
    service(ServiceImpl) {
        repository = repository
    }
}
```

This won't work:

```
beans {
    service(ServiceImpl) {
        repository = repository
    }
    repository(RepositoryImpl)        
}
```

That's because code in closure it executed line-by-line.

This is something we aren't used to in Spring - XML definition is parsed as a one DOM, in Java config the bean definitions are methods, so declaration order is not important.

I made some efforts to break this closure to mimic the Java config (closure/method per bean) but the code I came with was extremely ugly and verbose.

Do anyone has any idea how to refactor this closure to multiple order-independent units of code?

<sup>P.S. I understand that this definition style came from Grails, so maybe Grails community already has the answer?</sup>

Comment: Can you not do `ref("repository");`?

Comment: Not sure I understood your comment...

Comment: The comment about using ref("repository") is a suggestion to accomplish what you are looking to do. Using ref instead of a variable name as you have in your example is the same as using the Spring ref attribute for a bean reference. Give it a try.

Comment: Yay! It's a standard Grails config trick, I suppose? Adding `grails` tag was a good decision :)
Do you want to add an answer? If not, I'll add one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment about using `ref("repository")` is a suggestion to accomplish what you are looking to do. 
Using `ref` instead of a variable name as you have in your example is the same as using the Spring ref attribute for a bean reference.

You can read more about this, and other features of the Spring bean builder DSL in the documentation section for [Grails and Spring](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html).